# Favicon Only Works with IP

Tags: html, favicon

EDIT:Solved, had to restart Firefox twice for some odd reason.

Note: I use firefox on my main computer.

I made a favicon recently for my website, so I put it into the root directory as "favicon.ico" as you would usually do. I refreshed my page, and it didn't work. I cleared my cache, still didn't work. Then I just type in my IP into the address bar, and it worked. I go to my chromebook and type my url, and I get the Freenom logo as a favicon in chrome. I have tried using the `<link>` tag in my headspace, and that does not work either. Does anybody know what's going on? Since Freenom's favicon is showing, they might have something to do with it.

Ill put the link here, but I'm removing it when my problem is solved.

Comment: The favicon shows perfectly fine for me on Firefox when the page is opened via URL. The icon is an animated white text box typing "TTF".

Comment: Might be something with browser cache or proxy cache.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Huh. I'll go through it one more time, just to make sure everything is deleted.

Comment: Ensure you haven't bookmarked a link to your site prior to the favicon being in place. Sometimes that can be cached along with the bookmark. Worked fine for me also, on Firefox 45.0.2 (on Windows).

Comment: Okay, it's working now. I restarted, but I did that already after I cleared my cache. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

This site is awesome to use https://realfavicongenerator.net/
It generates all the favicons for all devices out now. [This page](https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/) has a good example

Comment: I do to, I make 1 260px X 260px and upload it to that link. It puts out 28 different sized icons, a manifest.json, a browserconfig.xml along with  with code to put in the <head> section of the website and it is for every available device.  [read this FAQ]https://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#.Vxrf6kfPSSo